# HP PC won't load grub

Tags: grub2, 22.04

I have installed Ubuntu in dual boot.
When I start the pc (HP), it wont display the grub dual boot menu, it will start automatically with Windows.
I need to press F9 when I start the PC in order to display the grub menu.
Is there a way to make it work the proper way?
Thanks.

Comment: Standard HP issue. HP does not support use of efibootmgr which grub also uses to change boot order to have Ubuntu first in UEFI boot menu. You have to go into HP's system settings & change boot order there. Grub only boots working Windows so make sure fast startup/hibernation & bitlocker are off. Or you can always boot from HP's UEFI menu. HP - escape + F9 for UEFI boot menu, F10 for UEFI/bios settings
Screenshot of HP's UEFI settings change of boot order
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2490924&page=2

Comment: Right, i changed boot order, and it s ok now.

Answer (score 2):

Standard HP issue.
HP does not support use of efibootmgr which grub also uses to change boot order to have Ubuntu first in UEFI boot menu. You have to go into HP's system settings & change boot order there.

Grub only boots working Windows so make sure fast startup/hibernation & bitlocker are off. Or you can always boot from HP's UEFI menu.

Note Windows updates may turn on fast startup or run UEFI firmware update resetting to defaults. So if issues recheck all settings you changed to get Ubuntu to work.

HP - escape + F9 for UEFI boot menu, F10 for UEFI/bios settings

Screenshot of HP's UEFI settings change of boot order

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2490924&page=2