The option to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 11 during instalation has disapeared
The first time I tried to install Ubuntu I was told I needed to turn off Bitlocker. I did that an tried to install again, but the only two options on the install menu were erase drive or manual partitioning. My link that I got during boot repair was https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Vz7c6BDxwp/
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/HP/DI.efi /efi/HP/diw.efi 
                       /efi/HP/BIOSUpdate/BiosMgmt.efi 
                       /efi/HP/BIOSUpdate/CryptRSA.efi 
                       /efi/HP/DEVFW/DevFwUpdate.efi 
                       /efi/HP/DEVFW/DevFwUpdate32.efi 
                       /efi/HP/DEVFW/HpDevFwUpdate.efi 
                       /efi/HP/DEVFW/HpDevFwUpdate32.efi 
                       /efi/HP/SystemDiags/CryptRSA.efi 
                       /efi/HP/SystemDiags/DI.efi 
                       /efi/HP/SystemDiags/SysDiags.efi 
                       /efi/HP/SystemDiags/diw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 8 or 10
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sda and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
                       location.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sda: /dev/sda already mounted or mount point busy.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Windows 8 or 10 on nvme0n1p3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Raptor Lake-P [Iris Xe Graphics] simpledrmdrmfb from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, noble, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: F.04(15.4) from Insyde
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,2001,3002,2002,2004
Boot0000* USB Hard Drive (UEFI) - USB (USB) UsbWwid(781,5591,0,04019605d8f01301e203e517469df483536188d1daa758b9295d4659a7cfa10ce0830000000000000000000025cc936100990818915581072bb17ba)/HD(2,GPT,1cf7d054-8db5-4194-971c-3c8665684807,0xb610ec,0x279c)RC
      dp: 03 10 fa 00 00 00 81 07 91 55 30 00 34 00 30 00 31 00 39 00 36 00 30 00 35 00 64 00 38 00 66 00 30 00 31 00 33 00 30 00 31 00 65 00 32 00 30 00 33 00 65 00 35 00 31 00 37 00 34 00 36 00 39 00 64 00 66 00 34 00 38 00 33 00 35 00 33 00 36 00 31 00 38 00 38 00 64 00 31 00 64 00 61 00 61 00 37 00 35 00 38 00 62 00 39 00 32 00 39 00 35 00 64 00 34 00 36 00 35 00 39 00 61 00 37 00 63 00 66 00 61 00 31 00 30 00 63 00 65 00 30 00 38 00 33 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 32 00 35 00 63 00 63 00 39 00 33 00 36 00 31 00 30 00 30 00 39 00 39 00 30 00 38 00 31 00 38 00 39 00 31 00 35 00 35 00 38 00 31 00 30 00 37 00 32 00 62 00 62 00 31 00 37 00 62 00 61 00 37 00 / 04 01 2a 00 02 00 00 00 ec 10 b6 00 00 00 00 00 9c 27 00 00 00 00 00 00 54 d0 f7 1c b5 8d 94 41 97 1c 3c 86 65 68 48 07 02 02 / 7f ff 04 00
    data: 52 43
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,6c653c78-2afd-4c50-90ef-cb4753f7af4a,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)57494e444f5753000100000088000000780000004200430044004f0042004a004500430054003d007b00390064006500610038003600320063002d0035006300640064002d0034006500370030002d0061006300630031002d006600330032006200330034003400640034003700390035007d00000000000100000010000000040000007fff0400
      dp: 04 01 2a 00 01 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 08 00 00 00 00 00 78 3c 65 6c fd 2a 50 4c 90 ef cb 47 53 f7 af 4a 02 02 / 04 04 46 00 5c 00 45 00 46 00 49 00 5c 00 4d 00 69 00 63 00 72 00 6f 00 73 00 6f 00 66 00 74 00 5c 00 42 00 6f 00 6f 00 74 00 5c 00 62 00 6f 00 6f 00 74 00 6d 00 67 00 66 00 77 00 2e 00 65 00 66 00 69 00 00 00 / 7f ff 04 00
    data: 57 49 4e 44 4f 57 53 00 01 00 00 00 88 00 00 00 78 00 00 00 42 00 43 00 44 00 4f 00 42 00 4a 00 45 00 43 00 54 00 3d 00 7b 00 39 00 64 00 65 00 61 00 38 00 36 00 32 00 63 00 2d 00 35 00 63 00 64 00 64 00 2d 00 34 00 65 00 37 00 30 00 2d 00 61 00 63 00 63 00 31 00 2d 00 66 00 33 00 32 00 62 00 33 00 34 00 34 00 64 00 34 00 37 00 39 00 35 00 7d 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 7f ff 04 00
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
      dp: 7f ff 04 00
    data: 52 43
Boot3002* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC
      dp: 7f ff 04 00
    data: 52 43

e34c4135d75ce5708a2939554a087183   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bootx64.efi
43b07ac69d248fb8d91d0a68aa6e7897   nvme0n1p1/HP/DI.efi
4cb826c171bf0068336542af34de3ef3   nvme0n1p1/HP/diw.efi
9b7bf7d157657719a078d9578ba1b329   nvme0n1p1/HP/BIOSUpdate/BiosMgmt.efi
a96537c7fa189564b38473456b33f7e5   nvme0n1p1/HP/BIOSUpdate/CryptRSA.efi
f4b09f533ea8d51318fa4c7d1aaa83cb   nvme0n1p1/HP/DEVFW/DevFwUpdate.efi
b76da453c2b6674b181499640a4d78fc   nvme0n1p1/HP/DEVFW/DevFwUpdate32.efi
4751131d1ba1d2c9b9aee387fa3dbea0   nvme0n1p1/HP/DEVFW/HpDevFwUpdate.efi
8382684a03312e7d1e0b23ff46edf4f2   nvme0n1p1/HP/DEVFW/HpDevFwUpdate32.efi
a96537c7fa189564b38473456b33f7e5   nvme0n1p1/HP/SystemDiags/CryptRSA.efi
43b07ac69d248fb8d91d0a68aa6e7897   nvme0n1p1/HP/SystemDiags/DI.efi
f14fff0811d2608cfc2df36deb58b980   nvme0n1p1/HP/SystemDiags/SysDiags.efi
4cb826c171bf0068336542af34de3ef3   nvme0n1p1/HP/SystemDiags/diw.efi
23837e7f81b5b729c2cc673d3da56273   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi
e34c4135d75ce5708a2939554a087183   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
3029d8cf512ca3d3dec4bf64c2d0d20c   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p3   : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p4   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p4   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk identifier: 62441B58-240E-4015-8C0D-FBDF6E518123
             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1      2048     534527    532480   260M EFI System
nvme0n1p2    534528     567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p3    567296  998920191 998352896 476.1G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p4 998920192 1000202239   1282048   626M Windows recovery environment
Disk sda: 114.6 GiB, 123048296448 bytes, 240328704 sectors
Disk identifier: 1CF7D054-8DB5-4194-971E-3C8665684807
        Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sda1        64  11931883  11931820   5.7G Microsoft basic data
sda2  11931884  11942023     10140     5M EFI System
sda3  11942024  11942623       600   300K Microsoft basic data
sda4  11943936 240326655 228382720 108.9G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:123GB:scsi:512:512:gpt: USB  SanDisk 3.2Gen1:;
1:32.8kB:6109MB:6109MB::ISO9660:hidden, msftdata;
2:6109MB:6114MB:5192kB::Appended2:boot, esp;
3:6114MB:6115MB:307kB::Gap1:hidden, msftdata;
4:6115MB:123GB:117GB:ext4::;
nvme0n1:512GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:INTEL SSDPEKNU512GZH:;
1:1049kB:274MB:273MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:274MB:290MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:290MB:511GB:511GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:511GB:512GB:656MB:ntfs:Basic data partition:hidden, diag, no_automount;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                  PARTLABEL
sda         iso9660  2024-04-24-11-29-09-00                                                    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS amd64 
├─sda1      iso9660  2024-04-24-11-29-09-00               1cf7d054-8db5-4194-971f-3c8665684807 Ubuntu 24.04 LTS amd64 ISO9660
├─sda2      vfat     37B6-BC6E                            1cf7d054-8db5-4194-971c-3c8665684807 ESP                    Appended2
├─sda3                                                    1cf7d054-8db5-4194-971d-3c8665684807                        Gap1
└─sda4      ext4     c4346525-19a3-4ea4-a5a5-44166dfe76eb 37babc8e-8d7a-4722-b8c1-8090b22f452e writable               
nvme0n1                                                                                                               
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     AE47-EC41                            6c653c78-2afd-4c50-90ef-cb4753f7af4a SYSTEM                 EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p2                                               dd2539c2-0355-42f8-8ed6-1d13b007c18c                        Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs     C8FA124DFA123860                     e0c2697f-58d9-4bf8-8afc-1a3c42310448 Windows                Basic data partition
└─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     4A9607E79607D27D                     3cbb8b45-530d-4a7b-b88e-68d2364f4c40 Windows RE tools       Basic data partition

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                               Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1                                                174.9M  32% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p3                                                   63G  87% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p4                                                   67M  89% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
/dev/sda1                                                          0 100% /cdrom
efivarfs                                                       19.9K  87% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/nvme0n1p1                                                vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/nvme0n1p3                                                fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p4                                                fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda1                                                     iso9660         ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================


/dev/nvme0n1p4: unknown GPT attributes
8000000000000001

mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/nvme0n1p3 /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3 

Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the MBR.
Additional repair would be performed:  win-legacy-basic-fix

The boot report said that:
The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the MBR. Additional repair would be performed:  win-legacy-basic-fix.

You also have to turn off Windows fast startup which sets hibernation flag. When set Linux NTFS driver will not default mount NTFS partitions to prevent damage or loss of data when hibernation is restored by Windows. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation  What model HP? HP often makes it more difficult but not impossible to install and configure UEFI boot. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1497845/hp-pc-wont-load-grub

Sorry for the late response, but my computer is a hp envy 360. I turned off fast startup but the option still hasn't shown up.

Have you updated UEFI firmware from HP? HP seems to have used 360 as a model number for years and each year has somewhat different issues. Of for each generation of HP issues are often common across multiple models. HP X360 Update UEFI F20, probably newer now
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2439220 You may not have Optane. HP Spectre x360 15t  Optane issue
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474790 [Guide] Older:  Install Ubuntu 18.04 on HP Spectre x360 13"
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2414086
