Media test failure / BootDevice not found right after installing
I just installed latest Ubuntu 24.04 from a live USB and right after rebooting my laptop (HP Elitebook 840) complains saying PXE-E61: Media test failure. It then says Boot Device Not Found. This problem did not happen with older Ubuntu versions at all. I have installed several versions of Ubuntu before in the same laptop without any problems at all.
Now if I remove the drive from the laptop and connect it to an old desktop computer (15 years old) it does boot like a charm with no problems at all.
Again in the laptop from the live USB running sudo efibootmgr returns EFI variables are not supported on this system. I thought it might have something to do with the EFI system, but my old computer desktop also reports EFI variables are not supported on this system so I am lost.
Please note that I have no access to the BIOS in my laptop.
I tried to run Boot-Repair both in simple and advanced mode, but that does not solve anything.
I paste below the content of dmidecode of the laptop
# dmidecode 3.5
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.
33 structures occupying 1686 bytes.
Table at 0xA9E3F000.

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    Version: M71 Ver. 01.05
    Release Date: 03/26/2015
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 10 MB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        PC Card (PCMCIA) is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        EDD is supported
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        Smart battery is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Function key-initiated network boot is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
        UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 1.5
    Firmware Revision: 150.84

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
    Product Name: HP EliteBook 840 G2
    Version: A3008D510B03
    Serial Number: 5CG52813R2
    UUID: eb5ea17f-14ae-11e4-8905-62af3003c0ff
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: G8R99AV
    Family: 103C_5336AN G=N L=BUS B=HP S=ELI

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 2, 16 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
    Product Name: 2216
    Version: KBC Version 96.54
    Serial Number: PEVEC00WB8X05O
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis:  
    Chassis Handle: 0x0010
    Type: Unknown
    Contained Object Handles: 0

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 3, 17 bytes
Chassis Information
    Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
    Type: Notebook
    Lock: Not Present
    Version: Not Specified
    Serial Number: 5CG52813R2
    Asset Tag: 5CG52813R2
    Boot-up State: Safe
    Power Supply State: Safe
    Thermal State: Other
    Security Status: Other
    OEM Information: 0x00000000

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 4, 42 bytes
Processor Information
    Socket Designation: U3E1
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: Core i7
    Manufacturer: Intel(R) Corporation
    ID: D4 06 03 00 FF FB EB BF
    Signature: Type 0, Family 6, Model 61, Stepping 4
    Flags:
        FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
        VME (Virtual mode extension)
        DE (Debugging extension)
        PSE (Page size extension)
        TSC (Time stamp counter)
        MSR (Model specific registers)
        PAE (Physical address extension)
        MCE (Machine check exception)
        CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
        APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
        SEP (Fast system call)
        MTRR (Memory type range registers)
        PGE (Page global enable)
        MCA (Machine check architecture)
        CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
        PAT (Page attribute table)
        PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
        CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
        DS (Debug store)
        ACPI (ACPI supported)
        MMX (MMX technology supported)
        FXSR (FXSAVE and FXSTOR instructions supported)
        SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
        SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
        SS (Self-snoop)
        HTT (Multi-threading)
        TM (Thermal monitor supported)
        PBE (Pending break enabled)
    Version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5600U CPU @ 2.60GHz
    Voltage: 1.1 V
    External Clock: 100 MHz
    Max Speed: 3600 MHz
    Current Speed: 3100 MHz
    Status: Populated, Enabled
    Upgrade: Socket BGA1168
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x0008
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x0009
    L3 Cache Handle: 0x000A
    Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Core Count: 2
    Core Enabled: 2
    Thread Count: 4
    Characteristics:
        64-bit capable
        Multi-Core
        Hardware Thread
        Execute Protection
        Enhanced Virtualization
        Power/Performance Control

Handle 0x0006, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L1 Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 32 kB
    Maximum Size: 32 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Asynchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Asynchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Parity
    System Type: Data
    Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L1 Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 32 kB
    Maximum Size: 32 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Asynchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Asynchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Parity
    System Type: Instruction
    Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L2 Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 2
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 256 kB
    Maximum Size: 256 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Asynchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Asynchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    System Type: Unified
    Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Handle 0x000A, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L3 Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 3
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 4 MB
    Maximum Size: 4 MB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Asynchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Asynchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Multi-bit ECC
    System Type: Unified
    Associativity: 16-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0015, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: Ctrl0Port0
    Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
    External Reference Designator: Primary HDD Bay
    External Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
    Port Type: SATA

Handle 0x0016, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: Ctrl0Port5
    Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
    External Reference Designator: Docking Station Upgrade Bay
    External Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
    Port Type: SATA

Handle 0x0017, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: Ctrl0Port4
    Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
    External Reference Designator: eSATA
    External Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
    Port Type: SATA

Handle 0x0018, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: Ctrl0Port3
    Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
    External Reference Designator: Docking Station eSATA
    External Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
    Port Type: SATA

Handle 0x0019, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: Ctrl0Port2
    Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
    External Reference Designator: mSATA
    External Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
    Port Type: SATA

Handle 0x001A, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: Ctrl0Port1
    Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
    External Reference Designator: Upgrade Bay
    External Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
    Port Type: SATA

Handle 0x001C, DMI type 9, 13 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: PCI SLOT1
    Type: 32-bit PCI
    Current Usage: Available
    Length: Long
    ID: 1
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        PME signal is supported
        SMBus signal is supported

Handle 0x0012, DMI type 10, 6 bytes
On Board Device Information
    Type: Video
    Status: Enabled
    Description: 32

Handle 0x001B, DMI type 11, 5 bytes
OEM Strings
    String 1: FBYTE#6J6S6b757H7M7Q7W7s7zaBaEapaqasauawbPbSbUce.4R;
    String 2: BUILDID#14WWCSBA601#SABE#DABE;
    String 3: ABS 70/71 79 7A 7B 7C
    String 4: CSM v01.5B
    String 5: HP_Mute_LED_0_0
    String 6: www.hp.com

Handle 0x001F, DMI type 13, 22 bytes
BIOS Language Information
    Language Description Format: Abbreviated
    Installable Languages: 14
        en-US
        da-DK
        nl-NL
        fi-FI
        fr-FR
        de-DE
        it-IT
        ja-JP
        no-NO
        pt-PT
        es-ES
        sv-SE
        zh-CN
        zh-TW
    Currently Installed Language: es-ES

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 16 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0000
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8 GB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: Bottom-Slot 1(left)
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 18122200
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: M471B1G73QH0-YK0  
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Memory Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x0003, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0000
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4 GB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: Bottom-Slot 2(right)
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Hynix/Hyundai
    Serial Number: 19632416
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: HMT451S6BFR8A-RD  
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Memory Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x0005, DMI type 19, 31 bytes
Memory Array Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x002FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 12 GB
    Physical Array Handle: 0x0000
    Partition Width: 2

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x001FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 8 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x0001
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x0005
    Partition Row Position: 1
    Interleave Position: 1
    Interleaved Data Depth: 1

Handle 0x0004, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00200000000
    Ending Address: 0x002FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 4 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x0003
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x0005
    Partition Row Position: 1
    Interleave Position: 2
    Interleaved Data Depth: 1

Handle 0x001D, DMI type 22, 26 bytes
Portable Battery
    Location: Primary
    Manufacturer: 33-42
    Name: CM03050
    Design Capacity: 50060 mWh
    Design Voltage: 11250 mV
    SBDS Version: 1.1
    Maximum Error: Unknown
    SBDS Serial Number: 07F4
    SBDS Manufacture Date: 2020-04-13
    SBDS Chemistry: LION
    OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000

Handle 0x0011, DMI type 32, 20 bytes
System Boot Information
    Status: No errors detected

Handle 0x0013, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation: 32
    Type: Video
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 1
    Bus Address: 0000:00:02.0

Handle 0x0014, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation: WLAN
    Type: Ethernet
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 1
    Bus Address: 0000:03:00.0

Handle 0x000B, DMI type 130, 20 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        82 14 0B 00 24 41 4D 54 00 00 00 00 00 A5 00 00
        00 00 00 00

Handle 0x000C, DMI type 131, 64 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        83 40 0C 00 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
        F8 00 C3 9C 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 0A 00
        E8 03 25 00 00 00 00 00 C8 00 A2 15 00 00 00 00
        04 16 00 00 00 00 00 00 76 50 72 6F 00 00 00 00

Handle 0x001E, DMI type 137, 12 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        89 0C 1E 00 01 00 F0 03 F0 FF 00 00

Handle 0xFFFD, DMI type 127, 4 bytes
End Of Table


How was the USB media made? Was it properly set to EFI or BIOS as needed? Did you test the ISO and verify it was good? Look at the info here and check it out. Please use the edit function and add this info to the question. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

I tried to create the usb several times with unetbootin from Linux and later with Rufus from a windows machine. I tried two different pen drives. However, as I said, the installation drive boots fine under another machine, so the ISO must be ok. I suspect it has to do with EFI. I tried creating the usb with Rufus as GPT/UEFI(no CSM) but then the laptop refuses to even launch the liveUSB

I just checked again and the liveUSB made with Rufus as GPT partiton and UEFI(no CSM) target it says on boot "Error: BIOS/Legacy boot of UEFI-only Media"

Hit the esc buttom, unforrtunately PXE has become one of the boot orders that starts before your actual boot, since you do not have access to bios you can not change the order and have to hit the esc buttom for every boot. That is if your grub works.

hi Amar, That does not solve the problem. When I hit esc I get the boot devices, choose hardrive and back again to square one. The problem is that the BIOS does not boot grub for some reason. BTW, I just moved the hard drive to an old laptop and it does work, so grub should be fine. It must be something with the HP's BIOS I guess

I dont think grub is the problem. As I said, if I move the hard drive to old computers grubs works fine and Ubuntu loads without any problem. It seems to be the computer not finding the grub for some reason. I suspect it might be some option in the BIOS, in which case I cannot solve it because the BIOS is locked by a password... thanks anyway

Many with various HP systems have reported that you have to go into HP's UEFI settings (not boot meenu) and in boot tab set "ubuntu" entry as first in boot order. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1497845/hp-pc-wont-load-grub HP - escape  + F9 for UEFI boot menu, F10 for UEFI/bios settings

Ok it looks like this is the issue. My problem is that I cannot access the BIOS because it is password protected. The funny thing is that this machine has been running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS for months (until last thursday) and the problem only appeared after the new reinstall. I have tried to install 22.04.4 and it gives the same error. I guess the previous install happened before a BIOS update and now there is something in the BIOS that wont like the new systems.
