Boot issues when installing Ubuntu on an HP EliteBook
I am trying to install Ubuntu on an old HP Elitebook with 225 GB of SSD disk space, 8MB RAM and a 2 processor Core i5 CPU. I have been partially successful, but how can I configure the boot-up without needing to select the grub.efi file? (See the questions below)
(Failed) installations using legacy boot method:
I used Rufus to create bootable Ubuntu 24.04 installation media on a USB stick. I then installed Ubuntu accepting all the defaults. I chose the second option to install Ubuntu by erasing everything and reformatting the desk. I discovered later that my BIOS boot mode was set to Legacy. There are three boot options which are set in the BIOS settings.
   Legacy
   UEFI Hybrid (with CSM)
   UEFI Hybrid (without CSM)
You open the BIOS settings by holding down the Esc key during boot.
I rebooted and removed the USB stick, and Ubuntu failed to boot. The boot process reported that it could not find an OS on the laptop.
I therefore did some googling and found a link which suggested using GParted and Boot-Repair. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition
I rebooted from the USB stick, opened GParted, and found out that my partitions looked like this:
| Partition | File system      | Size     | Used | Unused | Flags |
|---------- | ---------------- | -------- | ---- | ------ | ------| 
| /dev/sda1 | grub.core.img    | 1.00 MiB | 0   | 0 | bios_grub
| /dev/sda2 | ext4             | 223.57 GiB | 12.8 GiB  | 210 GiB   
| unallocated   | unallocated          | 1.00 MiB   

I think these partitions were created / reconfigured during the Ubunto installation process.    I messed about with trying to create a another 1 GB boot Partition - but my knowledge of boot processes is non-existent.  Do I keep the grub partition?  Should I have three partitions or two partitions?  I tried two or three installs, but I had no luck.
Successful installation using UEFI:
I then changed my BIOS settings to "UEFI Hybrid (with CSM)". I installed again. This time it worked except one issue;  when I reboot the Laptop goes into an infinite loop on Startup and the HP logo just flashes on the screen every 2 seconds. I therefore hit the escaped key and Selected F9 - Boot Device Options. I then selected the second Option: Boot from EFI File. It asked me to select file system.  There is only one option to select. I then selected \EFI. I then selected Ubuntu.  I then selected grubx64.efi.  It looks like I was selecting a file called: /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
I then hit return and the laptop booted normally.
Boot-Repair output:
I then ran Boot-Repair to see if that would help. It ran successfully and gave me this output:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XD4yCmGvBK/
boot-repair-4ppa2081                                              [20241013_0937]

============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================

modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/6.8.0-45-generic

Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub-efi of
sda2,
using the following options:  sda1/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file


/boot/efi added in sda2/fstab
/dev/sda2/boot/efi not empty

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda2/etc/default/grub

===================== Reinstall the grub-efi of /dev/sda2 ======================

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.12-1ubuntu7
modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/6.8.0-45-generic
modprobe efivars

efibootmgr -v (filtered) before grub install
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001
Boot0000* Notebook Hard Drive   BBS(HD,,0x0)0000000000001f00000002000000010100000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000100
Boot0001* Notebook Ethernet BBS(128,,0x0)010000000000190000000000000002009b0000cf80000000410b00cfdb0000cf000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001500
Boot0002* USB Hard Drive 1 - USB3.0 FLASH DRIVE BBS(HD,,0x900)0200000000000000000000000000030c00000000020000090000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000001300
Boot0003* USB Hard Drive 2 - Seagate Expansion  BBS(HD,,0x900)0300000000000000000000000000030c00000000020000090000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000001400
Boot0004* Ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,6fe1541f-5240-47fe-a074-dbdaceb931a9,0x800,0x219800)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)

uname -r
6.8.0-45-generic

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
df /dev/sda1
mv /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

efibootmgr -v (filtered) after grub install
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0000,0001
Boot0000* Notebook Hard Drive   BBS(HD,,0x0)0000000000001f00000002000000010100000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000100
Boot0001* Notebook Ethernet BBS(128,,0x0)010000000000190000000000000002009b0000cf80000000410b00cfdb0000cf000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001500
Boot0002* USB Hard Drive 1 - USB3.0 FLASH DRIVE BBS(HD,,0x900)0200000000000000000000000000030c00000000020000090000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000001300
Boot0003* USB Hard Drive 2 - Seagate Expansion  BBS(HD,,0x900)0300000000000000000000000000030c00000000020000090000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000001400
Boot0004* Ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,6fe1541f-5240-47fe-a074-dbdaceb931a9,0x800,0x219800)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)

update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-45-generic
Found memtest86+ 64bit EFI image: /boot/memtest86+x64.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda2/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the The OS now in use - Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS entry (sda1/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file) !


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (linux):   The OS now in use - Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on sda2

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller from Intel Corporation
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-45-generic root=UUID=5261dd13-2453-48f2-a15c-ee00ce23dba8 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
df -Th / : /dev/sda2      ext4  218G   11G  197G   5% /

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 68IBD Ver. F.46(15.70) from Hewlett-Packard
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this installed-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0000,0001
Boot0000* Notebook Hard Drive   BBS(HD,,0x0)0000000000001f00000002000000010100000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000100
Boot0001* Notebook Ethernet BBS(128,,0x0)010000000000190000000000000002009b0000cf80000000410b00cfdb0000cf000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001500
Boot0002* USB Hard Drive 1 - USB3.0 FLASH DRIVE BBS(HD,,0x900)0200000000000000000000000000030c00000000020000090000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000001300
Boot0003* USB Hard Drive 2 - Seagate Expansion  BBS(HD,,0x900)0300000000000000000000000000030c00000000020000090000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000001400
Boot0004* Ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,6fe1541f-5240-47fe-a074-dbdaceb931a9,0x800,0x219800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB
sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : isnotESP, fstab-has-bad-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
sda1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
sda1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 223.57 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk identifier: 9677917D-56FC-428D-9689-BD409E8C6EFF
       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sda1     2048   2203647   2201600     1G EFI System
sda2  2203648 468858879 466655232 222.5G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:240GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA Apacer AS340 240:;
1:1049kB:1128MB:1127MB:fat32::boot, esp;
2:1128MB:240GB:239GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                           
├─sda1 vfat   4691-070E                            6fe1541f-5240-47fe-a074-dbdaceb931a9       
└─sda2 ext4   5261dd13-2453-48f2-a15c-ee00ce23dba8 86f63776-925e-405c-aec7-881f9eef6005       

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                        Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2              196.7G   5% /
efivarfs                63.9K  44% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sda2              ext4            rw,relatime

===================== sda1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid 5261dd13-2453-48f2-a15c-ee00ce23dba8 root hd0,gpt2 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sda2/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   5261dd13-2453-48f2-a15c-ee00ce23dba8
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda2/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/5261dd13-2453-48f2-a15c-ee00ce23dba8 / ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during curtin installation
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0
UUID=4691-070E  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1

======================= sda2/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`( . /etc/os-release; echo ${NAME:-Ubuntu} ) 2>/dev/null || echo Ubuntu`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

==================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 158.341762543 = 170.018172928  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 137.675777435 = 147.828240384  boot/vmlinuz                                   2
 137.675777435 = 147.828240384  boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-45-generic                  2
 137.675777435 = 147.828240384  boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
 162.925777435 = 174.940221440  boot/initrd.img                                2
 162.925777435 = 174.940221440  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-45-generic               2
 162.925777435 = 174.940221440  boot/initrd.img.old                            2

===================== sda2: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18133 Apr  4  2024 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43202 Apr  4  2024 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14513 Apr  4  2024 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   786 Apr  4  2024 25_bli
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13120 Apr  4  2024 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1174 Apr  4  2024 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   722 Apr  6  2024 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr  4  2024 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr  4  2024 41_custom

This output says:
Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the OS now in use - Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS entry (sda1/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file) !
How can I get this laptop to boot automatically so I don't need to manually select /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi?
Should I be using Legacy or UEFI Hybrid (with CSM or without CSM)?

Most with HP have said they have to go into UEFI settings, not one time boot menu & change boot order there. Then you can directly boot Ubuntu. CSM is BIOS boot.  CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode Your ubuntu boot entry in UEFI of 0004 is a standard UEFI boot entry that uses partuuid to find UEFI boot files in ESP - efi system partition. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1497845/hp-pc-wont-load-grub Screenshot of HP's UEFI settings change of boot order
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2490924&page=2

I have absolutely the same problems with Ubuntu 24.04. If installed with classic bootable USB-stick, it can't find the BootDevice. If installed with UEFI USB-stick, I have to select the UEFI-file.

I suggest you:
1- Set the BIOS boot mode to Legacy.
2- Start a live Ubuntu session.
3- Boot from the live session, gparted (sudo gparted)
4- Unmount and delete the partitions.
5- Create a msdos partition table.
6- Create a 40gb primary partition on ext4.
7- Create a 24gb primary partition on swap.
8- Create a primary partition of the rest of the gigs on ext4
9- Apply the changes.
10- Close gparted and start the installation.
11- Install with manual partitioning, selecting the
first partition for /, the second for swap and the last for /home, Grub on the sda ​​mbr.
swap 24 gigs if hibernating, 16 gigs if not hibernating.

OK.  Thank you kyodake.  I am doing it now.  For /dev/sda1,  I don't have an msdos option for the FileSystem, so I am using fat32 with a size of 1.05 MiB.   For /dev/sda3, there is no FileSystem called "swap", so I am using linux-swap.    Also I specified the sizes as 40gb and 24 gb as requested, but After click on the green tick, the sizes were 39.06 Gib and 23.44 GiB respectively.  I am proceding ...  Fingers crossed.

I tried to install twice.  The installation process crashed both times.  I don't know if it user error, but it seams that pre-formating the disks with Gparted seams pointless.  During the ubuntu installation process, there are two options: Automatic or Manual partitioning.  Both options overwrite any previous partitioning.   The main query I have is what type of filesystem to use for the /dev/sda1.  I have 5 options:   Ext4, XFS, Btrfs, VFAT or Swap.  also what size? I tired VFAT and 500 MiB - but the install crashed.

Well I tried again.  I let tghe Automatic install option of the installer create the first drive (sda1).  I then use Gparted to look at the configuration of the partitions.  It created a 1 Mib grub.core.img partition with flags: for bios and grub.  and a second ext4 partion (sd2) for the test of the Memory.  I then ran the install again using "Manual Patitioning".  I then used the Manual Paitioning GUI, deleted sda2 and crated 3 new partitions sda2-4 as you described above.  The instlal finished OK, but when I reboot, the screen says:  "Please Install an Operating system on your hard disk".

So I am back to square 1.  I am beginning to get frustrated.  I have been at this for a day.  Maybe I should switch to Mint or Centos?

I have given up.  The EliteBook is going in the bin.  I can't even access the BIOS menu anymore.  I have Ubuntu installed on Oracle VirtualBox.  I will use that instead.  My only advice is:  do not install the Guest Tools.  It locked up my Ubunto image twice.

You've made life difficult for yourself. You had a UEFI installation on a GPT disk according to paste-bin. All you had to do was to ensure your BIOS was set to UEFI without CSM. The msdos option is for those who don't have a UEFI computer., or set to CSM if you do have a UEFI. But your PC was set to boot from grubx64.efi. which is a UEFI set-up.  This has nothing to do with what Linux dist you use. Installing Linux on a VM is unnecessary and making life more complicated...But that's your choice.
